# Men=mars and female=venus symbols in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I wish to create a plot that uses venus (U+2640 ♀) symbol to represent females and mars (U+2642 ♂) symbol to represent males. If you have used these before, please share with me how to set them as markers in `pylab.scatter()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(range(3), range(1,4), 200, marker=ur'$\u2640$')
plt.scatter(range(3), range(2,5), 200, marker=ur'$\u2642$')
```

[image]

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#symbols) you find the complete list of available symbols.

Comment: Is it possible to color code these symbols to show a third variable using the colorbar?

Comment: @user3810603: You can pass an optional argument, e.g. ```edgecolor=plt.cm.rainbow([0, 0.3, 0.6])```.

Comment: I have used the optional argument edgecolor as suggested by Falko. Then I thought I could also use facecolor to represent a fourth variable. But attempt in vain. Any suggestions if it is possible to change the circular fill in the venus and mars symbols?

Comment: @user3810603: I don't think this is possible. The symbols are unicode characters and not geometric shapes. Thus, they don't have a colored face, but only lines on a transparent background. And whether the line is closed or not depends on the font. You might, however, find a (dirty) hack combining mars/venus symbols with circular markers. But I doubt that you want to do that. Furthermore, I question the readability of a plot with so many dimensions in each marker.

Answer (score 1):

An other option is to use [mathtext unicode symbols](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#symbols) for [marker](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#markers):

```
plt.scatter(..., marker=ur'$\u2640$')
plt.scatter(..., marker=ur'$\u2642$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Python 3, you must remove the `r`s before the string, leaving only the `u`s,

```
plt.scatter(..., marker=u'$\u2640$') # female symbol
plt.scatter(..., marker=u'$\u2642$') # male symbol
```

otherwise you will get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.